# Why is max-width not working?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS -Code:

```css
.afbeelding {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.afbeeldingCentreren {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.vrij {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div name="bericht" id="bericht">
  <div class="vrij" />
  <div class="afbeelding afbeeldingCentreren" style="width:1944px;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x2000" />
    <div class="bijschrift" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  The message
</div>
```

The intention is that the image can't make the page wider then the screen. It's not working however. I don't see why. Can somebody help me. I hope this is enough information. Sorry for the Dutch class names.

Comment: Hard to say when the image link is invalid. http://jsfiddle.net/vw3q7xnq/ with a background color for clarity of the elements.

Comment: `<div>` is not a self-closing tag. You need a closing `</div>` tag for each opening tag.

Comment: @Aibrean Replace it in your test with `http://placehold.it/2000x2000` or something similar.

Comment: The div with the  vrij Class is invalid (XHTML)

Comment: if your image is larger than the parent it'll stick out the side, you might want to add `.afbeeldingCentreren img {max-width : 100%; height: auto}`

Comment: @Sumurai8 I've rolled back your revision because we don't know how wide the source image is. Making such an assumption changes the original code too much and doesn't honor OP's intent.

Comment: When you say "screen" do you mean the actual computer screen or the browser window?

Comment: @TylerH OP says "The intention is that the image can't make the page wider then the screen". This implies that the problem is with an image that is bigger than the screen. Having a link to an image that does not exist in an executable stack snippet does not help the question in any way or form.

Comment: @Sumurai8 FWIW, the Stack Snippet was not part of the original question. The problem stands, but should be up to the OP to add appropriate adjustments like that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS.

```
.afbeelding img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}
```

For the `max-width` value enter the width of your image. This will prevent it from sketching and pixelating when viewed on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the max-width for the image, so your html would be:

```
<img src='yaddayadda' class='notBig'>...
```

and your css:

```
.notBig {
  max-width: 95%;
}
```